# What are the scenarios where Apple records HRV(Heart Rate Variability) in the background?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

Apple definitely computes **HRV(Heart Rate Variability)** when someone uses Breathe App (in Mindfulness) on their Apple Watch and when we closely look at the details of data collected in HealthKit app, it depicts **Algorithm Version as 2** But Apple also records HRV in some other scenarios which depicts **Algorithm Version as 1**. What are those **scenarios**?

[image: Details of HRV value coming from Breathe Application]

[image: Details of HRV value coming from Apple driven background process]